# Density of Square Rationals

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

This is a homework question I have in my analysis class.

Prove that for all $x, z \in \Bbb Q$ with $0 < x < z$, there exists $y \in\Bbb Q$
such that $x < y < z$ and $y$ has a rational square root (i.e., $y = w^2$
for some $w \in Q$.) 
Here, $\Bbb R$ is the set of all real numbers, and $\Bbb Q$ is the set of all rational numbers.

I tried the following:
Let $x,z \in \Bbb Q$ with $0 < x < z$. Since $x < y < z$, we can say $\sqrt x < \sqrt z$. 
Since $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, there exists $w \in\Bbb Q$ such that $\sqrt x < w < \sqrt z$. 
If we square the expression, we get $x < y^2 < z$, so $w^2 = y$. QED

I was told that this isn't a proper way to prove this statement and haven't been able to figure out how to start it correctly.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't see a problem with your method...certainly my first thought was the same as yours. (well, there is some confusion between $w$ and $y$ but I figure that is a typo). Was there a specific criticism you were given?

Comment: The comment I was told was that I didn't define what the square root of x and z meant, and that there wasn't a clear description of how y was found. Also, I was asked if I could solve this without using real numbers, and I didn't have an answer that could be used without real numbers. So an answer without using real numbers would be great!

Comment: You can't use square roots until you have proven that for every $b > 0$ there exists a $c > 0$ so that $c^2 = b$.  However that usually is proven fairly early in an analysis course.  You also must show that if $c^2 < d^2$ and $c>0;d>0$ then $c < d$ but that's very easy.

Comment: Oh, and you have to prove that the rationals are dense in the reals.  But seriously, as objections, I have to wonder what *was* taught in the class.

Comment: How would you go about proving those statements?

Comment: Probably an adaptation of the usual proof demonstrating the density of the rational numbers works here (essentially, $x<z$ in $\Bbb Q$ implies there exists a natural number $n$ such that $nx<nz$ with $nx,nz\in\Bbb N$ and $nx-nz>1$ giving us a natural number contained in the interval. Dividing by $n$ provides the desired rational number between the original $x$ and $z$.)

Comment: @Clayton That seems like overkill.  Since $x<z$, we have $$ 2x < x+z < 2z \implies x < \frac{x+z}{2} < z.$$ But $\frac{x+z}{2} \in \mathbb{Q}$, so we are done.

Comment: @Xander: density in the reals. You need something like this to prove density.